# CodeIgniter: Rewrite URL with method parameter as subdomain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have a CI Project where I want to change the URL like below:

`www.example.com/index.php/Controller/method/param1`
to
`param1.example.com/index.php/Controller/method`

Is this possible using just CI? Like routes. Or we need to .htaccess?
If possible, are there any risks or is it a bad practice?
Also does it affect SEO?

EDIT: This rewrite should happen only for `Controller` controller.

EDIT: I think the meaning came out wrong. When a user enters a URL like
`param1.example.com/Controller/method` It has to fire the `method` in `Controller` and pass `param1` as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create redirect controller (controllers/Redirect.php), that will redirect browser Something like this:

> ```
> <?php
>   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
>
>   class Redirect extends CI_Controller {
>
>       public function index($method,$domain) {
>           $redirect_url =  'http://www.' . $domain . '.example.com/index.php/Controller/' . $method;
>           redirect($redirect_url,'refresh');
>       }
>
>   }
> ?>
> ```

2. Add this line in application/config/route.php

> $route['Controller/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'redirect/index/$1/$2';

You are done. Enjoy :)

Comment: This is a redirect. I do not have a subdomain. I need to dynamically modify the URL to look like its in a subdomain. Please check second EDIT to the question. THanks

Comment: Then you should use .htaccess